# multidimensional array of images in python

Tags: arrays, image, numpy, multidimensional-array

How can I in python declare an empty (multidimensional) array, that can store images? I dont want to use something like

```
array.append(image1)
array.append(image2)
```

but rather something like

```
array[0,0]=image1
array[0,1]=image2
array[1,1]=image3
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use append for dynamic sizing, but if you know the final size beforehand, you could use an `np.empty()` to generate an empty array of objects:

Example using strings instead of image objects:

```
>>> myarray=np.empty((2,2), dtype=object)
>>> myarray[0,0]='image1'
>>> myarray[0,1]='image2'
>>> myarray[1,1]='image3'
>>> myarray
array([['image1', 'image2'],
       [None, 'image3']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a two dimensional array:

```
arr2d = [[0 for i in range(10)] * 5] # creates an array of 5 arrays filled with 10 zeroes
x = 0
y = 0
```

You can access the 0 at x,y as follows:

```
print(arr2d[y][x]) # 0 at 0,0 you can switch x and y it doesn't really matter
```

You can insert an image as so:

```
arr2d[y][x] = image # arr2d[y][x] == image
```